# Hiding the title from the "More" Navigation Bar in the Tab Bar Controller consistently

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, edit, title

I have the following issue.

I have a background image for my UINavigationBar so I have to hide all the titles from the Navigation Bars. The problem comes with the "More" Navigation Bar of the TabBarController. I have managed to hide it, but this only happens the first time its shown. When I select an item from within it, and go back, "More" is displayed again.

Im guessing I should disable the title inside some sort of "viewWillAppear" delegate method for the "More" View Controller, yet I have no idea how to do that.

This is the first time I display "More", as you can see, the Logo is there (smudged of course :) ) however, More is not:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/68985587@N02/6272805069/lightbox/

This is the View Controller of the first Item in the "More" View Controller:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/68985587@N02/6272805241/in/photostream/lightbox/

After I press the "More" left button in the Navigation Bar to go back, I get this:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/68985587@N02/6273332152/in/photostream/lightbox/

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution came by setting the delegate to the more view controller and acting upon the delegate method.

First, I set the delegate to the "more" view controller (in my case in the appdelegate):

```
[tbc.moreNavigationController setDelegate:self];
```

the I proceeded to implement the following method:

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if([viewController.title isEqualToString:@"More" ])
    {
        UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
        viewController.navigationItem.titleView = label;
        label.text = @"";   
    }

}
```

This effectively gets called not just the first time but everytime the view controller came up. Even when a back button was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You can check what tab of the *UITabBarController* was clicked by implementing the delegate method `tabBar:didSelectItem:` of *UITabBarDelegate*. If the fifth item (the "More" item) was clicked, then you can set the title like this:

```
[[[tabBarController moreNavigationController] visibleViewController] setTitle:@""];
```

I hope, it works, I haven't tried it. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, I did manage to hide the title the first time. The problem was that every time I pressed back, the title showed up again. I did however find a solution by using a part of your solution! Ill post it separately cuz i dont think it fits here :).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look at this link [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html)

Hig, according to more than 5 icons are not recommended for use. You can search links for TabBar.

Comment: Thanks for the links, they where pretty helpful. However, they didnt really solve my issue. At first I thought the guidelines would suggest that I shouldnt really do the whole changing the title. However I found that they do allow it if it serves the look and feel of the app, which i think in this case it does. Thanks for the links anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can displace the label:

```
UITabBarItem *i = self.tabBarController.tabBar.items[4];
[i setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0., 300.)];
```

so it has an offset from top that let it disappear...